# Is raise ImproperlyConfigured is missing in django library

Tags: python, django

django library
path:  django\views\generic\detail.py 
class : SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin
why raise ImproperlyConfigured is not mentioned in 2nd last line of the code?

```
class SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin(TemplateResponseMixin):

    template_name_field = None

    template_name_suffix = '_detail'


    def get_template_names(self):
        """
        Return a list of template names to be used for the request. May not be
        called if render_to_response() is overridden. Return the following list:

        * the value of ``template_name`` on the view (if provided)
        * the contents of the ``template_name_field`` field on the
          object instance that the view is operating upon (if available)
        * ``<app_label>/<model_name><template_name_suffix>.html``
        """
        try:
            names = super().get_template_names()
        except ImproperlyConfigured:
            # If template_name isn't specified, it's not a problem --
            # we just start with an empty list.
            names = []

            # If self.template_name_field is set, grab the value of the field
            # of that name from the object; this is the most specific template
            # name, if given.
            if self.object and self.template_name_field:
                name = getattr(self.object, self.template_name_field, None)
                if name:
                    names.insert(0, name)

            # The least-specific option is the default <app>/<model>_detail.html;
            # only use this if the object in question is a model.
            if isinstance(self.object, models.Model):
                object_meta = self.object._meta
                names.append("%s/%s%s.html" % (
                    object_meta.app_label,
                    object_meta.model_name,
                    self.template_name_suffix
                ))
            elif getattr(self, 'model', None) is not None and issubclass(self.model, models.Model):
                names.append("%s/%s%s.html" % (
                    self.model._meta.app_label,
                    self.model._meta.model_name,
                    self.template_name_suffix
                ))

            # If we still haven't managed to find any template names, we should
            # re-raise the ImproperlyConfigured to alert the user.
            if not names:
                raise

        return names
```

Comment: `raise` is re-raising the `ImproperlyConfigured` exception that caught by `except ImproperlyConfigured:`.

Comment: oh got it.Thank you so much Alasdair